# MergerFacor effect on indexes

Tags: indexing, solr

my solrconfig.xml configuration is as :

```
<mainIndex>
   <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <mergeFactor>5</mergeFactor>
    <maxMergeDocs>10</maxMergeDocs>
    <maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
    <unlockOnStartup>false</unlockOnStartup>
  </mainIndex>
```

and index size is 12mb. but when i change my mergeFactor i am not finding any effect in my indexes., ie. the no of segments are exactly same. i am not getting which configuration will effect the no of segments. as i suppose it is mergefactor.
and my next problem is which configuration defines the number of docs per segments and what will be the size of this segment so that next segments will be created

please make me clear about these points

Answer (score 0):

To your questions:

- MergeFactor: If you have a mergefactor of 10 .. every 10 documents there will be a new segment up to the number of 10segements than each segment is added to a segment of 100 and so on.
- MaxMergeDocs give you the maximum number of documents a segment can take before starting to merge in a new segment.

So in the end both will have an influence on segments

Update:

If you use the dataImportHandler be sure that you dont auto-optimize to maxSegments=1 on a full import to see effects.

Comment: @fyr: Than why, when i change merge factor i can not see the effects on my indexes

Comment: maybe your testset or parameters are not appropriate. Test it with a merge factor of 2 and maxMergeDocs 10000 and a merge factor of 2 and a maxMergeDocs of 100. Index in both cases 1000 documents it will differ.

Comment: @fyr: as u can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533581/how-to-optimize-solr-indexes , i have only 2881 num of documents, than what should be my configuration to view the effects

Comment: did you test it with my parameters and a subset of 1000 documents ?

Comment: yes i have testedwith with your parametes. but what i feel is if i have only 2881 docs, than it will create only 1 segment and merge factor will not effect on these num of docs. please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544838/mergerfactor-and-maxmergerdocs-effecting-num-of-segments-created

Comment: Is there a possibility to extend your post with the data handler and solr configuration... either with these both parameters or the mergepolicy entry depending on your solr/lucene version ?