# How to optimize solr indexes

Tags: optimization, solr

when i run solr/admin page i got this information, it shows optimize=true, but i have not set optimize=true in configuration file than how it is optimizing the indexes.
and how can i set it to false then .

```
Schema Information

    Unique Key: UID_PK

    Default Search Field: text

    numDocs: 2881

    maxDoc: 2881

    numTerms: 41960

    version: 1309429290159

    optimized: true

    current: true

    hasDeletions: false

    directory: org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory:org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory@ C:\apache-solr-1.4.0\example\example-DIH\solr\db\data\index

    lastModified: 2011-06-30T10:25:04.89Z
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt say "optimize = true" or that it will "optimize something". It says that your index is currently optimized. Thats a difference it describes only the current status of your index.

The best way to lookup this kind of thing is:

1. Insert a couple of rows
2. Lookup this value it will show "optimized"
3. Delete a row
4. Lookup again this value it will say "not optimized"

Comment: Why so that when i insert a row it is optimized and when i delete a row it is not optimized.

Comment: and if i do no want to optimize in nay case then what i have to do ??

Comment: it does not automatically optimize thats the point. Its not an optimized index because the document is not removed physically it is only "flagged" as deleted.

Comment: fyr: than waht i hav to do if i want to remove deleted  documents phisycally..as i suppose i need to set optimized=true when i run dataimport, is it ??

Comment: If you want to delete them physically you need to optimize the index right. But whenever you optimize the index thats another thing. Its a pretty heavy operation depending by the size of the index.